# TypeScript @types modules fail to resolve each other

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

When I use npm to install TypeScript definitions like this

```
npm install --save @types/express
```

I cannot use the installed modules as they fail to resolve each other. For example, @types/express requires @types/express-static-server-core, but as `@types/express/index.d.ts` contains a relative path to `express-static-server-core`, the module cannot be resolved:

```
node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts(16,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'serve-static'.
node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts(17,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express-serve-static-core'.
node_modules/@types/serve-static/index.d.ts(15,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express-serve-static-core'.
node_modules/@types/serve-static/index.d.ts(16,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mime'.
```

How can I solve this issue? What is the best way to install TypeScript definitions?

As far as I know, typings is deprecated, so I tried to just install the type definitions from @types and then use

```
tsc --target ES5 --module commonjs index.ts
```

but it does not work yet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 I ended up using the old typings tool, but if I remember correctly, some of my newer projects use the new `@types/*` modules without problems. Be careful when working on client *and* server code, you might need to use multiple instances of typescript.

Answer (score 1):

On the chance this is related, in one project, I was using generic types with express:

```
import { ParamsDictionary, Request, ... } from 'express-serve-static-core';
// ...
app.get<ParamsDictionary, UserDetails>(...);
```

That worked. When I tried to do the same thing in another project that wasn't using generic types:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express-serve-static-core';
```

I was getting '**Unable to resolve path to module 'express-serve-static-core**'.

When I changed my import to:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
```

The problem went away.

Comment: This was it for me, it was driving me NUTS! Thanks! `import {Request} from 'express';` did it